# how to pass variables between jade templates

Tags: templates, variables, pug

I am using a template as a base, and want it to be aware of some variables set in the page that is using it...

File: template.jade

```
vars = vars || {some:"variables"}
!!! 5
head
    title vars.some
```

File: page.jade

```
vars = {some:"things"} //- this does not get used from within template.jade
extends template
```

I want the compiled page.jade to have a title "things"

Comment: this limitation really sucks.  those variables need to go to the extended template.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I find solution [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/654)

pass block with variables

template.jade:

```
!!!
html
  block vars
  head
      title #{pageTitle} - default www title
  body
```

page.jade

```
extends template
block vars
  - var pageTitle = 'Home'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when you are including a template that extends a layout

Comment: Just found this. Perfectly solves my issue. Pretty clean solution as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use blocks:

template.jade:

```
!!! 5
head
    block title
        title variables
```

page.jade:

```
extends template
block title
    title things
```

Else you have to define the variables in your script (for example express).
As far as I know, variables can only be passed around via includes, but not upwards to the layout (template.jade in your case).

Answer (score 2):

I thought that blocks wouldn't work for me because I needed to use the variable in multiple places.

```
// base.jade
pageTitleVar = "Parent's Title"
!!!
title !{pageTitleVar}
h1 !{pageTitleVar}
```

Turns out you can actually specify the same block twice in the parent template and whatever the child template passes to it gets duplicated.

```
// base.jade
pageTitleVar = "Parent's Title"
!!!
title
  block pageTitleBlock
    !{pageTitleVar}
h1
  block pageTitleBlock
    !{pageTitleVar}

// child.jade
extends base
pageTitleVar = "Child's Title"
block pageTitleBlock
   !{pageTitleVar}
```

Blocks FTW

Answer (score 2):

A great and commented solution to add title like this:
**"My Project - The Page"**.

Or just this:
**"My Project"**

template: template.jade

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
head
    //- setting the page title to be dynamic
    block vars
        - var defaultTitle = "My Project"
        - var pageTitle = pageTitle
    title #{defaultTitle}#{pageTitle}
```

some page: page.jade

```
extends base
//- custom page title
block append vars
    pageTitle = " - The Page"
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using [template includes](http://learnjade.com/tour/template-includes/)?

```
// vars.jade
- var name = "Chris"
#{ nick = "StackOverflow"  }


// page.jade
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    h1= title
    include vars
    p Welcome to #{title} #{name} #{nick}
```